# Implicit parameters cannot be found when imported (from an Object)

Tags: scala, implicit

Why can not the code below find the imported implicits from `MyProducers`? In my understanding this should work fine because the implicits are in scope.

```
Error:(16, 34) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type MyProducers.ListProducer[Int]
  val stuffInt:Int = getHead[Int]()
Error:(16, 34) not enough arguments for method getHead: (implicit evidence$2: MyProducers.ListProducer[Int])Int.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
  val stuffInt:Int = getHead[Int]()
Error:(18, 43) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type MyProducers.ListProducer[String]
  val stuffString:String = getHead[String]()
Error:(18, 43) not enough arguments for method getHead: (implicit evidence$2: MyProducers.ListProducer[String])String.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
  val stuffString:String = getHead[String]()
```

Code:

```
object Resolver {

  import MyProducers._
  import MyProducers._

  def getList[T:ListProducer]():List[T]= implicitly[ListProducer[T]].produceList


  def getHead[T:ListProducer]():T= getList[T]().head

  val stuffInt:Int = getHead[Int]()

  val stuffString:String = getHead[String]()

  val im=ip  // this compiles fine, so implicits are in scope
  val sm=sp
}

object MyProducers{
  trait ListProducer[T]{
    def produceList:List[T]
  }
  object IntProducer extends ListProducer[Int]{
    override def produceList = List(22, 42)
  }
  implicit val ip=IntProducer

  object StringProducer extends ListProducer[String]{
    override def produceList = List("stuff", "Shiraly")
  }
  implicit val sp=StringProducer
}
```

What is strange, that this code compiles fine:

```
object Resolver {

  import MyProducers._
  import MyProducers._
  trait ListProducer[T]{
    def produceList:List[T]
  }
  object IntProducer extends ListProducer[Int]{
    override def produceList = List(22, 42)
  }
  implicit val ip=IntProducer

  object StringProducer extends ListProducer[String]{
    override def produceList = List("stuff", "Shiraly")
  }
  implicit val sp=StringProducer


  def getList[T:ListProducer]():List[T]= implicitly[ListProducer[T]].produceList


  def getHead[T:ListProducer]():T= getList[T]().head

  val stuffInt:Int = getHead[Int]()

  val stuffString:String = getHead[String]()

  val im=ip
  val sm=sp
}
```

Any idea why the first code does not compile while the second does ?

Comment: Implicit vals and defs *must* have type annotations - try that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit vals and defs need to have type annotations on them. Add those, and the implicits will be found.